# Search and Replace "(" " " and "[" in Vi - Regex

Tags: regex, linux, vi

I have this line:

```
[app_user] ([id], [nome], [email], [login], [senha], [tipo], [data])
```

I want to replace for this:

```
(id, name, email_address, username, password, access_type, created)
```

How I do that?
I try this (in vi):

```
:%s/\[app_user\] \+\\( \[id\], \+\[nome\], \+\[email\], \+\[login\], \+\[senha\], \+\[tipo\], \+\[data\]\\) /\\( id,name,email_address,username,password,access_type\\)/
```

But didn't work.

I think the problem is betwen " \+//(", because I try run, only simple search:

```
/\[app_user\] \+
```

And works.
I'm not expert in Regex.

Comment: There's no reason for the `\\ ` in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable all special characters except the backslash in your search pattern use [`\V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) (very nomagic), that would make much easier to write it:

```
:%s/\V[app_user] ([id], [nome], [email], [login], [senha], [tipo], [data])/(id, name, email_address, username, password, access_type, created)
```